# Is this complexity of the algorithm correct?

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to figure out these algorithms and calculated the complexity as following, is it correct?

```
for (i=1; i<2*n; i++) // runs 2n-1 times 
   for (j=1; j<=n; j*=3)// runs log n(base 3)
      for (k=n; k>=1; k--)// runs n times
```

Complexity: O(n^2 log n)

```
int t=0;
for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) //runs n times
   for(int j=0; j*j<4*n; j++) //runs (2√n)
      for(int k=1; k*k<=9*n; k++) //runs (3√n)
         t++;
```

Complexity: O(n^2)

```
int x=0;
for(int i=1; i<=n; i=i*3){  //runs 1, 3, 9, 27.. 
   if(i%2 != 0) // true for values above
      for(int j=0; j<i; j++) // runs n times
         x++;
 }
```

Cant figure out this one

Please explain if i am wrong.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  this is not a homework testing service

Comment: The last one might be O(log^2(n)).

Answer (score 0):

```
int x=0;
for(int i=1; i<=n; i=i*3){  //log n
   if(i%2 != 0) // true for values above
      for(int j=0; j<i; j++) // runs n times
         x++;
 }
```

Here, you can see that the first loop runs with `O(log n)` complexity. And the inner one runs until `i` i.e., `n` times, which indicates whatever the `n` value is, the increment of the `j` value is constant i.e., `1` which literally means `O(n)`. So combining both. According to master theorem, inner `T(n)` and outer `T(logn)`, we get the complexity as `O(nlogn)`.

Answer (score 0):

Run time for first loop is `O(log_3(n))`. `if` comment is always true, so second loop run until `j<i` (not `j<n`).

So total run time is as follows:

1+3+9+27+...=∑{i=0to log_3(n)}(3^i)==(3*n-1)/2

> So complexity is `O(n)`